# How to prove if a set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm looking through my real analysis text book, and I KNOW, that this particular set is bounded:

The set of complex numbers Z, such that |z| is less than or equal 1. I know that it is contained in a ball of radius one, but I don't know how to go about stating it matter of factly.

But the definition of a bounded set says "A set E is bounded if there is a real number M and a point q that is an element of X such that d(p,q) < M. Where "d(p,q)" means the distance from p to q is less than M. Does the M and q have to be the same for no matter what value of p I choose?

Comment: Yes: you have to have one $q$ and $M$ that work for all $p\in E$. In your case, what happens if you take $q=0$ and $M=1$?

Comment: Yes. In your particular example, just set $M=1,q=(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $S = \{z:|z|\le 1\}$ is indeed bounded.

Setting $q = 0$ and $M = 2$, we may indeed say that $d(p,q) < 2$ for every $p \in S$.